# java create NESTED zip recursively in memory

Tags: java

This is how I create a simple zip archive with 3 files

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("out.zip"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String s = "hello world " + i;
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("text" + i + ".txt");
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(s.getBytes());
            zos.closeEntry();
        }

    }

    baos.writeTo(fos);
```

How can I put a zip inside zip recursively in one turn on the fly? Is there any way to put `ZipOutputStream` or `ZipEntry` inside each other?

EDIT:

Solution as Mark suggested:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("out.zip"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream resultBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream zipOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ZipOutputStream zos2 = new ZipOutputStream(zipOutStream)) {

        String s = "hello world ";
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("text.txt");
        zos2.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos2.write(s.getBytes());
        zos2.closeEntry();
        zos2.close();
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("text.zip");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(zipOutStream.toByteArray());
        zos.closeEntry();
    }

    baos.writeTo(resultBytes);

    resultBytes.writeTo(fos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "inner" .ZIP file, you could use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`; then that zip will be built as data in RAM; so you can use the resulting byte array as the data for a `ZipEntry` in the outer .ZIP file.

Comment: Oh it was so easy. Thank you Mark. I just have to pass the first ByteArrayOutputStream bytes to the following ZipOutputStream.write() method.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to follow the solution using the 'ByteArrayOutputStream' but only manage to create corrupted zip files this way.

I ended up creating a nested ZipOutputStream directly like this:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myZipFile); ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("inner.zip");
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);

        ZipOutputStream nestedZos = new ZipOutputStream(zos);
        // write stuff to nestedZos
        nestedZos.finish();

        zos.closeEntry();  
}
```

The resulting zip file contains the nested structure and is valid.